# JSoup is not connecting website with login password

Tags: jsoup, java

I am trying to connect a website with JSoup but not working.

Here is my code:

```
        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.metalbulletin.com/Login.html?ReturnURL=%2fdefault.aspx&")
        .data("username", "94mkr@mail4gmail.com", "password", "jakdjique&THFI#")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.metalbulletin.com/Article/3838710/Home/CHINA-REBAR-Domestic-prices-recover-after-trading-pick-up.html")
        .cookies(loginCookies)
        .get();

        Element article             = doc.getElementById("article-body");   
        Elements heading            = article.getElementsByTag("h1");
        Elements lead               = article.getElementsByClass("lead");
        Elements lead1              = article.getElementsByClass("articleContainer");

        System.out.println(lead);   
        System.out.println(lead1);
```

I just made a temp login/password so that you can check it 
I have noted that `http://www.metalbulletin.com/Login.html?ReturnURL=%2fdefault.aspx&` this generate a new link like: 
`https://account.metalbulletin.com/identity/login?signin=fab48076d8a4f74f52565dd6a9f47e65`

I tried a lot but still not able to access this website

**UPDATE**
I refined my code as under:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.metalbulletin.com/Login.html?ReturnURL=%2fdefault.aspx&")
    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
    .execute();

    response = Jsoup.connect("http://www.metalbulletin.com/Login.html?ReturnURL=%2fdefault.aspx&")
    .data("username", "94mkr@mail4gmail.com", "password", "jakdjique&THFI#")
    .cookies(response.cookies())
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute();

    Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.metalbulletin.com/Article/3838710/Home/CHINA-REBAR-Domestic-prices-recover-after-trading-pick-up.html")
    .cookies(response.cookies())
    .get();

    System.out.println(response.statusMessage()+"\n"+response.statusCode());
```

When I compile the output is:
`OK
200`
but when I continue to next part of data fetching like:

```
    Element article             = doc.getElementById("article-body");   
    Elements lead               = article.getElementsByClass("lead");
    Elements lead1              = article.getElementsByClass("articleContainer");

    System.out.println(lead);   
    System.out.println(lead1);
```

Then its giving up and showing data that is displayed to non logged in users

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to browse the website using the given credentials, I would suggest that you log in from a normal browser. Copy the cookies that the website generated and add them to an instance of CookieStore.

```
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    BasicClientCookie cookie1 = new BasicClientCookie("__gads", "ID=958b183c83ede6e8:T=1539776783:S=ALNI_MbFRRpTafZvTiJAjKmTB9oBQelWWw");
    cookie1 .setDomain(".metalbulletin.com");
    cookie1 .setPath("/");

    BasicClientCookie cookie2 = new BasicClientCookie("__utma", "167598498.350699797.1539776871.1539776871.1539776871.1");
    cookie2 .setDomain(".metalbulletin.com");
    cookie2 .setPath("/");
    ....
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie1);
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie2);
    ....
```

Then use the cookiestore when you create your connection pool.

```
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connManager.setMaxTotal(256);
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(64);
    ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy myStrategy = new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy();
    CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(getCookieStore())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
            .setConnectionManager(connManager).setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy).build();
```

Because anyway if you want to log in to the website. Then you need a way to handle the cookies and the tokens. This way the cookiestore will handle the cookies. You just have to call the website with the http client and parse the returned html with jsoup.

**Edit**:
These are the steps you need to follow:

1. Log in using your browser.
2. Create a BasicCookieStore that contains all the cookies that the browser saved. You can use the developer console and monitor which cookies are changing everytime you navigate around the website and thus figure out the most important ones. But to stay on the safe side, add them all.
3. Create the HttpClientManager and add the cookieStore to it.
4. Now consider yourself logged in and start calling the pages that you need to scrape. Just make a get request using the client pool that you generated. eg: to page "https://www.metalbulletin.com/Article/3838710/Home/CHINA-REBAR-Domestic-prices-recover-after-trading-pick-up.html"
5. If everything is done correctly, The request should return an HTML page source.
6. Use Jsoup.parse(stringHtml) to convert the string response into Document object..
7. Parse the response and extract the elements you need.
8. Make Another request.. get response as string.. parse html with jsoup.. repeat.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please let me know how will I use this in Jsoup? I am beginner. Tried a lot to understand your advice but not reached to the point as to how I embed into above my Jsoup Code

Comment: if I was able to write code to such extent that you mentioned step wise then I never used Jsoup but must write my own code. I am repeatedly confessing that I am beginner and this is my first post in this community. Please try to rectify my errors/logic by staying Jsoup API

Comment: still waiting for help